# How to disable Records Management doclib actions for particular site

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

I need to disable records management doclib actions like "Declare as a record, Declare version as record etc" in share document library browse and document details pages for a particular custom document site.

Please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you need to have them available in another document library?

Comment: yes Lista. I need those options to be disabled only to one site, the RM options should be available to other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you even use RM? If not, since RM is built as a separate module, you could simply stop using the whole module.

If you do use it, and you need to continue using it in some DM sites and stop using it in others, extending Share while building your own custom evaluator is the way to go.

Check the following link. If you wanted to disable the actions for everyone, you'd simply use the `evaluator.doclib.action.disableAction` on beans defining actions you want disabled.

Since you do not want this, you need to build a custom evaluator that would check the site name/description/whatever.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/doclib-override-extension-examples.html

Comment: I think there are out-of-the-box evaluators that can disable based on site name.